# If there is a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^3$, why is it said that it takes 3 numbers to determine a point in three-dimensional space?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, 3d

Looking up definitions of the mathematical concept of three-dimensional space, the notion that it takes three independent real numbers to specify a point in it seems to be the defining property of the "three-dimensional" in "three-dimensional space". I was very surprised to learn however that there is a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^n$ for any finite $n$, such as $3$. In other words, it is possible to specify any point in three-dimensional space with a single real number, as could be done for any other finite-dimensional space.

This seems like a huge disconnect between how we perceive mathematics and the physical world to be connected, and the definition of three-dimensional space itself. What gives? What is then the fundamental property that makes three-dimensional space different from, say, two-dimensional space?

Comment: Does that bijection preserve linear combinations? I.e. is true that (let's call the bijection $f$) $\forall x,y,a,b \in \mathbb{R}: f(ax+by)=af(x)+bf(y)$ ?

Comment: @Raskolnikov I don't know, but why is it relevant that it does or doesn't? I really don't know.

Comment: This kind of confusion is pretty common. It arises from an intuition about bijections that is far too narrow. Bijections have nothing to do with any geometric or topological properties of the sets, it's literally just about pairing off elements with each other (sometimes with flagrant disregard to notions like continuity).

Comment: The point is that you are talking about dimension, but you have not defined it mathematically and you just mention a map that is a bijection, but clearly does not preserve dimension in the naïve sense that you go from 1 to 3. To understand what goes wrong, you have to come up with a notion of dimension. The easiest is to talk about vector spaces and linear maps. There's other more general approaches like topological dimension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bijection is ugly and not useful for anything; in particular it is badly [discontinuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function), hence not differentiable, so it can't be used e.g. to do [differential geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry).

There is a theorem called [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) guaranteeing that there is no bijection between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ for $n \neq m$ which is continuous with continuous inverse (a [homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism)). More generally it guarantees that the dimension of a [topological manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold) is well-defined. Understanding what exactly this all means requires understanding what a [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space) is.